# How can I implement if statement in shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement

when I try to implement if statement in shell script, somehow I met this problem, what I want to do is when the input option is yes, prompt to ask users to enter longitude, latitude and width, if the input is not yes, then skip to end.

```
#!/bin/bash    
echo "Please enter keyword:"
read keyword
export keyword
echo "Do you want to search longitude and latitude? enter yes or no"
read option
if [[ $option=="yes" ]]; then
    echo "Please enter longitude:"
    read longitude
    export longitude
    echo "Please enter latitude:"
    read latitude
    export latitude
    echo "Please enter width:"
    read width
    export width
fi
```

Comment: spaces -> `if [[ $option == "yes" ]]; then`

Comment: @ZhichuZheng, keep in mind that the shell parses code by splitting it into tokens separated by whitespace. Particularly, the expressions in `[[ double brackets ]]` act differently based on the number of white-space separated words. When given a single argument (like "$option==yes") `[[` returns true if the argument has non-zero length, which your expression always has, regardless of the value of $option.